# How to get projection data (.prj) of raster image using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, ogr

I start with a boundary shape-file (think U.S. states) in lat/long that I convert to some projection, and then rasterize the result as a .tif.  What I need now are the *raster coordinates* of the original boundary points, as another shapefile.

With a .prf file for the raster projection, I can simply **ogr2ogr** the input shapefile with the .prj and get a shapefile where the points are now in raster-space; this is my initial inclination.  If there's a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestion.

tl;dr: I want to get the CRS/projection info for a raster coordinate system from a .tif file.

I would like to use command line tools.  ogr2ogr, gdal, etc.

Looking through the documentation of gdal/ogr2ogr, it seems I need WKT format, EPSG, etc for the projections.  Really, all I need to do is perform bilinear interpolation on the coordinates of the shapefile with the extents of the raster image.  Is there a quick tool to do something like this?

i.e., apply a function to every coordinate in a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You will use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) to do this from the GDAL command line or OSGeo4W shell. The syntax for inspecting a raster file is:

```
gdalinfo C:\path\to\raster
```

For more advanced use, if you are using Python/C# bindings to do this then you can deserialize the the output into a dict or object.

Comment: I have already stumbled upon gdalinfo, but I'm not sure how to apply the interpolation in the original shapefile.  I suppose my question should really say, "How can I apply an arbitrary function to all coordinates of a shapefile."  I would rather not write this myself as I'm sure it already exists.  I can't seem to find it though....